# Why am I getting matching query does not exist?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I get the following error:

```
DoesNotExist: PostalCode matching query does not exist
```

on the line below:

```
nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code='self.zipcode').location)
```

In an effort to troubleshoot the issue.  I went into my python shell and was able to run:

```
PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code='97202').location)
```

Which returned the proper zipcodes.  I think what this means is that I am inappropriately using self.zipcode in the original query?  I thought I should be using self.zipcode because basically the view is for an `edit_profile` form which has a `zipcode` field.  So I thought `self.zipcode` would be taking the users zipcode from that form and then running the query with that value.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here is more of the code if it helps:

views.py

```
@secure_required
@login_required
def profile_edit(request, username, edit_profile_form=EditProfileForm,
                 template_name='userena/profile_form.html', success_url=None,
                 extra_context=None, **kwargs):
profile = get_profile(user)
form = edit_profile_form(instance=profile, initial=user_initial)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid()

            nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code='self.zipcode').location)
            zip_codes = list(nearestzips.values_list('code', flat=True))
            user.nearbyzips = zip_codes

            return redirect(redirect_to)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Base form used for fields that are always required """
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'),
                                 max_length=30,
                                 required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'),
                                max_length=30,
                                required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # Put the first and last name at the top
        new_order = self.fields.keyOrder[:-2]
        new_order.insert(0, 'first_name')
        new_order.insert(1, 'last_name')
        self.fields.keyOrder = new_order

    class Meta:
        model = get_profile_model()
        exclude = ['user']

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        profile = super(EditProfileForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        # Save first and last name
        user = profile.user
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()

        return profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `''` from `self.zipcode`. Also you said that you want to get `zipcode` from a `form`, so,`self` is not defined, you need to get zipcode from `form` variable

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid()
            zipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
            nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code=zipcode).location)
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid error.  But now I get error: global name self is not defined.

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia you need to use form variable name, not self.

Comment: what about the line user.nearbyzips = zipcodes?  should it be user.nearbyzips or form.nearbyzips?

Comment: 'nearbyzips' is a model field for the same user, just like 'zipcode', so should i change it to form.nearbyzips?

Comment: but, bearbyzips is a list of zipcodes ? or what, that depends on what are you lookng for.

Comment: Oh I get it, It should be, `user.nearbyzips = zip_codes` and then `user.save()`

Comment: you need form.save() too. Yes, if not,your user wont gonna been save.

Comment: isn't form.save() responsible for saving all the data the user enters into the form?  nearbyzips is a form field, so why form.save() AND user.save() ?  It seems like user.save() is unnesasary no?

Comment: if you want to save it using `form.save`, then set `form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips'] = zip_codes` and then `form.save()`

Comment: Okay thanks, I made a new SO post, because you have helped me with the original issue.